# Imported curl command in Postman works as intended, but when I save as a request, it no longer works

Tags: curl, postman

Not sure why it doesn't work. All the headers seem correct / correctly ported over. Is there a chance that APIs can track if the request is coming from Postman, and if so, is there anyway to avoid that?